# (Quantitative) research methods for collocation analysis in corpus linguistics?

Tags: methodology, research-design, corpus-linguistics

I am trying to conduct a collocation analysis. This is a corpus linguistics research, doing so require me to test statistical significance using Mutual Information, as well as frequency normalization for multiple corpora analysis. What research method am I employing here? Quantitative methods? Mixed method?

So far, what I learn about quantitative research is more on the research design, a.k.a. how to manipulate variables of interests and control variable etc. My research does not really require me to conduct a lab-based research wherein control and variables of interest are necessary.

Any recommendation and enlightenment on research methods is highly valuable for me, thanks in advance!